# Testing AppService: System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: abp

Using the abp.io module template

Using the sqlite :memory: provider for my tests. Getting this error when I attempt to query using the IRepository<TEntity, Guid> service. It occurs whether I use it directly in a test method, or the instance injected into the service.

System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

Does anyone know what is causing this error, I can't seem to figure it out. Have I mis-configured something in the test modules?

```
            HolidaySchedule schedule = await _holidayScheduleRepository.GetAsync(x => x.TenantId == tenantId
                                                                  && x.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this issue, my problem was that I wasn't using the unit of work properly. My test cases needed to be wrapped in a WithUnitOfWork.. block which I overlooked.

```
    await WithUnitOfWorkAsync(async () =>
    {
        ISomeService service = GetRequiredService<ISomeService>();
        int result = await service.DoSomethingAsync();
        Assert.Equal(5, result);
    });
```